# change the margin using variable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the value of the `top` `margin` when hitting the up arrow key the code seems right to me but i don't know why it wont work !

**JavaScript**

```
var playerPosition = 0;

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if(key = 38) {
        playerPosition += 10;

    } else if(key = 40) {
        playerPosition -= 10;
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('player').style.marginTop = playerPosition+".px";

 }
```

**html/CSS**

```
.mainDiv {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: black;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .player {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 5px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    .bar {
        top: 30px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 5px;
        border-style: dashed;
        border-left: 5px;
        border-color: #FFF;
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
    }
    .ai {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 5px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 164px 0 0 10px;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    .ball {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        bottom: 69px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="sprite.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="player"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="ai"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetElementsByClassName Not Working As Expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412743/getelementsbyclassname-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292561/javascript-getelementsbyclassname-not-working-with-select, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289907/getelementsbyclassname-produces-error-undefined, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/why-getelementsbyclassname-does-not-work-for-me-what-does-it-return, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('player')` returns a `NodeList` of elements (array-like) that have the class `player`. You need to loop through the list and apply the style changes to each:

```
var players = document.getElementsByClassName('player');
for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
    players[i].style.marginTop = playerPosition+"px";
```

Or I guess if you only have one, apply it to the 0th element.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bzgt2sg/)

Comment: It returns a `NodeList` not an array.

Comment: Technically speaking, `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`, although that doesn't matter for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Function is called "getElements[...]", plural, so it returns an array of HTML elements with class name provided. Moreover in your conditional statements you used assignment operator (=) instead of comparison operator (==).
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ys3q78be/)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0].style.marginTop = playerPosition+"px";
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns a HTMLCollection. So, you have to specify the element to work.

for example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0].style.marginTop = playerPosition+".px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');
if ( document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.contains('MyClass') )
    document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.toggle('MyClass');
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.